# React-native datatable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-table-component

How to get a datatable component in react native with search and sort function?

I have used react-native-datatable-component which does not have search function and the styling of the table is very minimum.

please suggest any alternative or table component which can be used to overcome this issue.

i have used this code

```
import React from 'react';
import DataTable, { COL_TYPES } from 'react-native-datatable-component';

const SomeComponent = props => {
    return (
        <DataTable
            data={[ 
                { name: 'Muhammad Rafeh', age: 21, gender: 'male' },
                { name: 'Muhammad Akif', age: 22, gender: 'male' },
                { name: 'Muhammad Umar', age: 21, gender: 'male' },
                { name: 'Amna Shakeel', age: 22, gender: 'female' },
                { name: 'Muhammad Ammar', age: 20, gender: 'male' },
                { name: 'Muhammad Moiz', age: 13, gender: 'male' }
            ]} // list of objects
            colNames={['name', 'age', 'gender']} //List of Strings
            colSettings={[
              { name: 'name', type: COL_TYPES.STRING, width: '40%' }, 
              { name: 'age', type: COL_TYPES.INT, width: '30%' }, 
              {name: 'gender', type: COL_TYPES.STRING, width: '30%'}
            ]}//List of Objects
            noOfPages={2} //number
            backgroundColor={'rgba(23,2,4,0.2)'} //Table Background Color
            headerLabelStyle={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: 12 }} //Text Style Works
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: what error you are facing??wih your current code

Comment: I need a search function in this table.
Or do you know any other libraries that have search and sort functions in react-native?

Comment: you can render textbox along with it,and when use search somthing , you can process data or make api call before rendering datatable

Comment: You can try this library, not used it personally. Planning to test this out this weekend.

Docs
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table.html

Search bar page
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/searchbar.html